Pigeonhole Principle question in a Discrete Geometry Problem
Let $P_1,\dots, P_m$ be polygons contained in the unit square such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m \mathrm{area}(P_i) > n
$$
I want to use the pigeonhole principle to argue that there exists a point in the unit square that is contained in at least $n+1$ of the polygons. However, I am confused as to what the "pigeons" and "holes" should be in this context.
(The below argument is incorrect. Thanks to Chris Lewis for pointing this out)
Note that I was able to find a different way of arguing the result that doesn't really use the pigeonhole principle. My argument goes as follows: We can split up the sum:
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k_1} \mathrm{area}(P_i)\right) + \cdots + \left(\sum_{i=k_{n-1}+1}^{k_n} \mathrm{area}(P_i)\right) + 
\left(\sum_{i=k_{n}+ 1}^{m} \mathrm{area}(P_i)\right)
$$
where the first $n$ summations are each equal to $1$ and the last summation is $>0$.
Picking a point in one of the polygons in the last summation, we know that this point has to appear in a polygon in each of the previous summations, giving us our result. However this doesn't really use Pigeonhole.

How do you know you can split the sum that way? There may be no collection of polygons whose total area is exactly $1$. And I may have missed something, but I'm not sure how you get to "Picking a point in one of the polygons in the last summation, we know that this point has to appear in a polygon in each of the previous summations" (are you going for an induction argument here?).

Ah yes you're correct. That's my mistake. My argument is incorrect.

The canonical answer.
Let us refine $\sum_{i=1}^m \mathrm{area}(P_i)$ as follows. Let $S$ be the unit square and $[m]=\{1,\dots,m\}$. For each subset $A$ of $[m]$ put
$$P_A=\left(\bigcap_{i\in A} P_i\right) \cap \left(\bigcap_{i\in [m]\setminus A} (S\setminus P_i)\right).$$
It is easy to see that
$$\sum_{A\subset [m]} \mathrm{area}(P_A)=1$$
and
$$n<\sum_{i=1}^m \mathrm{area}(P_i)=\sum_{A\subset [m]} |A|\mathrm{area}(P_A).$$
Therefore there exists a subset $A$ of $[m]$ such that $\mathrm{area}(P_A)>0$ and $|A|>n$.
Any point of $P_A$ is contained in at least $n+1$ polygons, namely, in all polygons $P_i$, $i\in A$.

Thank you sharing this nice and elegant argument. I'm grateful for the answer and help.

I might be missing something (and/or being overly persnickety) but I think the first displayed equation should be $\sum_{A \subseteq [m]} \mathrm{area}(P_A) = 1$.

@JazzGuitar7 Thank you for your attention and sorry for the mispint and the delay with its correction (I thought that I already did this).

Let us try to follow my reasoning step by step, that I think is quite related to the Alex Ravsky answer.
Assume first of all the baby case $n=1$, so that you want to prove that if
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m Area(P_i)> 1
$$
then there is a point contained in at least two of the polygons among $P_1,\dots, P_m$. In other words, it there should be at least $2$ polygons with intersection non-empty.
Assume by contradiction that it is false, namely that $P_1,\dots, P_m$ are two-by-two disjoint. Then
$$
1<\sum_{i=1}^m Area(P_i)=Area(\sqcup_{i=1}^m P_i)\leq Area(square)=1
$$
that it is a contradiction. Thus, the thesis follows for the baby case $n=1$, which is also the key to understand what happens in general.
We prove the thesis in general by induction on $n$. We already proved the case $n=1$, so let us assume the thesis is true for each $n-1$ and we prove that it is true for $n$.
Assume by contradiction that the thesis is false, so that any choice of  $n+1$ polygons among $P_1,\dots, P_m$ gives an empty intersection.
Let us define new polygons $P_{ij}:=P_i\cap P_j$. Then any choice of $n$ polygons among $P_{ij}$, $i,j\leq m, i\neq j$, gives an empty intersection. Hence, by inductive hypothesis, we are forced to have
$$
\sum_{ij} Area(P_{ij})\leq n-1.
$$
However, we can obtain a contradiction as follows. Firstly, we observe that our union of $P_i$-polygons can be re-written better as:
$$
P_1\cup P_2=P_1\sqcup (P_2\setminus P_{12}),\qquad  P_1\cup P_2\cup P_3=P_1\sqcup (P_2\setminus P_{12})\sqcup (P_3\setminus (P_{13}\cup P_{23})),\qquad  \dots
$$
It is not difficult to prove the general formula
$$
P_1\cup P_2\cup \cdots \cup P_m=\sqcup_{i=1}^m \left( P_i\setminus \cup_{j<i}P_{ij}\right). 
$$
Now we can write
$$
1=Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+Area(P_1\cup \cdots \cup P_m)=Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+\sum_{i=1}^m \left(Area(P_i)-Area(\cup_{j<i}P_{ij})\right)\geq Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+\sum_{i=1}^m \left(Area(P_i)-\sum_{j<i}Area(P_{ij})\right) = Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+\sum_{i=1}^m Area(P_i)- \sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})
$$
Now we use the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^mArea(P_i)>n$ to obtain
$$
1\geq Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+\sum_{i=1}^m Area(P_i)- \sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij}) > Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+n -\sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij}) \implies \sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})>Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+(n-1)\implies \sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})>n-1,
$$
that is in contradiction with the inequality $\sum_{ij} Area(P_{ij})\leq n-1$ obtained above.
Thus we have proved that the thesis is true also for $n$, and so the thesis is true in general.
$\textbf{Remark:}$ As you can expect, here we have not really used the fact that $P_i$ are polygons. Indeed, we have only seen them as sets. Thus, roughly speaking, the thesis is true for any choice $P_1,\dots, P_m$ of sets whose area can be "computed". In other words, more precisely,   the thesis follows for any measure $Area$ in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ and any choice of $P_1,\dots, P_m$ measurable sets.
$\textbf{Update}:$ Reading the proof that I wrote I realised that we can obtain much more than the statement of the posed question. Indeed, I think it holds:
$\textit{Theorem:}$ Let $P_1, \dots, P_m$ polygons contained in the unit square such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^m Area(P_i)>n.
$$
Then there exist $n+1$ polygons among $P_1,\dots, P_m$ whose intersection has a positive area. In particular, the intersection of such polygons is non-empty.
$\textit{Proof:}$ Following the same proof as before, we get
$$
1\geq Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+\sum_{i=1}^m Area(P_i)- \sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})>Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)-\sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})+n \implies \sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})>Area((P_1\cup\cdots\cup P_m)^c)+n-1 \implies \sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})>n-1.
$$
Thus, for $n=1$ we get $\sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})>0$, so that it has to  exist $i,j$ such that $Area(P_{ij})>0$, and we are done.
Now, by induction on $n$, we suppose the statement is true for $n-1$ and we show that it is true for $n$. We use the above inequality to obtain that $\sum_{i,j}Area(P_{ij})>n-1$, so that, by induction hypothesis, there are $n$ polygons $P_{ij}$ whose intersection has a positive area. However, the intersection of such $P_{ij}$ polygons is exactly the intersection of $n+1$-$P_i$ polygons among $P_1,\dots, P_m$, and we are done.

Thank you so much for your beautiful post and thoughtful explanation.

You're welcome, thank you too for posting this interesting problem :)
